# Adding Code Assist feature to an Editor

Tags: intellisense, code-completion, code-assist

I would like to add a very basic assist feature to a text editor I am writing. Am interested in knowing how the code assist feature for major IDEs or Text Editors work. Can someone point me in the direction of links towards implementations of these, maybe in any of the major open source projects or even the data structures or basic designs that are usually followed for these...

Thanks